# How can I render a component in DOM body even if some other component renders it in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component, say `X` which is rendered by my `app` and in the DOM-body. I have another component `Y` which is rendered by the component `X` but the component `Y` should be opened in full-screen. So, I need to render this in `document.body` rather inside component `X` even if `X` renders it.

React Components' structure is:

```
app
    -X
         -Y (in Full Screen)
```

the structure now should look like:

```
<body>
    <div class="X">
         <div class="Y">
         </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and the rendered flow should be :

```
app.body
    -X
-Y
```

and the DOM structure should be:

```
<body>
    <div class="X">
    </div>
    <div class="Y">
    </div>
</body>
```

How can I do this. Also, I am using ES6 classes for making react-components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Starting from **React 16**, there is official support for [portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html).

> Portals provide a first-class way to render children into a DOM node
>   that exists outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component.

---

**I wouldn't recommend to use this solution as it is using an undocumented React API**. Disclaimer provided, here it is:

```js
class Portal extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this._renderLayer();
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this._renderLayer();
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById(this.props.container));
  }

  _renderLayer() {
    ReactDOM.unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer(this, this.props.children, document.getElementById(this.props.container));
  }
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

class Y extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Y</div>;
  }
}

class X extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div> 
        X
        <Portal container="Y">
          <Y />
        </Portal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<X/>, document.getElementById('X'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='X'></div>
<div id='Y'></div>
```

Comment: Hi, I am using `portal` for this problem and in the container, I am sending `container={() => document.querySelector( 'body' )}` and it is giving me following error:
`React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method`

Comment: Hi, it worked. Thanks. I was writing wrong `import` statement

Comment: You maybe can use the ordinary `React.render()` instead of the dangerous `ReactDOM.unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer()` if you don't need access to the context.

Answer (score 1):

Simply render each of your component in their own `<div>`:

```
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <div id="Y"></div>
</body>
```

And render each component separately:

```
React.render(ComponentApp, document.getElementById("app"));
React.render(ComponentX, document.getElementById("X"));
```

Comment: but `X` is rendered by `Y`. I know the structure of the DOM should look like this but how can I do that?

Comment: using ES6 classes for react component, so How would I write it there? Can you please tell me

Comment: Based on the way you describe your situation, you shouldn't be rendering `X` in `Y` as they don't logically fit into a hierarchy.  Is there any data that `Y` depends on from `X`? If so, can you obtain it some other way (eg, a centralized store like redux)?